# Is it incorrect to use length() to subset the last element of a vector?

Tags: r

I am taking Microsoft's online Data Science programme. In one of the courses, I ran into an error with some code which I feel is logical and should work just fine. I'm using DataCamp's IDE.

Here is the question that I was asked (the variables were pre-created and I was to use them in my code. Unfortunately, I can't provide the data stored in the variables):-

> Create a new list named key_skills, that contains three elements (in this order): - The second element of the `topics` vector inside the `skills` list. - The second element of the `context` factor inside the `skills` list. - The last element of the logical vector inside the `list_info` list, that's inside `skills`.

This is my code for the question :-

```
key_skills <- list(
    skills$topics[2], 
    skills$context[2], 
    skills$list_info[length(skills$list_info)]
)
```

Why is the code incorrect? The code for the last element in the list `key_skills` was marked wrong. I believe it should work just fine.

EDIT : I looked up the variable in the IDE, the logical vector is the 2nd one inside skills$list_info, the correct code for the last part is skills$list_info[[2]][length(skills$list_info[[2]])]

Thank you everyone!

another solution :
key_skills<- list(skills[[1]][2],skills[[2]][2],skills[[4]][[2]][4])

Comment: "Unfortunately, I can't provide the data stored in the variables" -- we don't need your data, nor do we need your background info or the actual problem you worked on. Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/28481250#28481250

Answer (score 5):

Since `list_info` is a list, it should be:

```
key_skills <- list(skills$topics[2], skills$context[2], 
skills$list_info[[length(skills$list_info)]])
```

`list[index]` gives you a list, while `list[[index]]` gives you the object at the index, which in your case should be the last element of the  boolean vector in `skills$list_info`.

Answer (score 0):

It should work fine, yes. There is however a simpler way to get the last element, using `tail`:

```
tail(skills$list_info, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Without an example dataset it's difficult to know for sure, but given your description of the problem it seems that since `skills$list_info` is a `list`, it may have several vectors in it. One of them is of class `logical`. So first determine which one is logical, then get the last element of that vector. Something like this:

```
inx <- which(sapply(skills$list_info, is.logical))
skills$list_info[[inx]][length(skills$list_info[[inx]])]
```

But, like I've said, without data it's impossible to be sure if this code does the job.